# Am able to access site via my IP, but not localhost anymore

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I'm working on a wordpress website installed on my box using WAMP, so I've always typed in 'localhost' into the address bar in order to access the site.
I've always had the apache rewrite module enabled
I then had the idea of allowing people on our LAN to access the site via my LAN IP.
To do this I edited this line of Apache's httpd.conf file (per instructions on this page http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/5155/how-access-wampserver-another-computer-lan.html)  :

```
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
#    Require all granted
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
Allow from localhost
```

(I changed 'Deny from all' to 'Allow from all')
Saved the file,
accessed my box via IP on an iPad mini, then another windows PC.
Come back to the machine that is running WAMP and I'm developing the site on, click one of the navigation links on the page, **then I get the 500 Internal Server Error**

So I can now only see the wamp menu and the site by typing my own IP in. Some images aren't loaded, and I get Error 500 when trying to login by typing my IP with '/wp-admin' after it (meaning that I can't log in to wordpress to edit anything either)

What is the problem here? I really need to be able to access 'localhost' and continue developing the website, but I can not figure this one out!
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to access `localhost/your-wp-dir-path/wp-admin/options-general.php` and in

**WordPress Address (URL)** option give value as `http://localhost/your-wp-dir-path`